# How to make own input method in Qt application?

Tags: qt, input

I would like to make an input method which is used only for **Qt desktop application.**
It like **Chinese(Pinyin)** input method in windows. Include script processing, rendering of words.
As it includes rendering of words, it can't be created with Keyboard Layout.
More over, when built-in with application, it can be use cross over other platform.

But, It **not like on-screen keyboard**.

Thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

The Qt way to implement this is to provide an input method plugin, see [general plugin development docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/main-snapshot/plugins-howto.html) and the [input method specific base class](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/main-snapshot/qinputcontextplugin.html).

With this you should be able to implement your own input method. Stuff like script processing and rendering is then up to your own plugin.